# Same name in parameter in two different methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

Please note this picture
[image]
I set break point in top method.but if look at the bottom method's parameter you can see value off top method.I know this is because naming but i want to know why?Related with `CLR` or compiler?

Comment: This is just a debugger artifact due to the name being the same. No harm is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio identifies what symbol you're hovering. It will find the string "conference". To display the value, the debugger will look for a symbol with that name in the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is just something related to the **debugger**, not the CLR or anything else. In any given scope, there is only one accessible variable or object with specified name, so the debugger does not try to distinguish the same names appearing in different palces.

Hovering over a *name* is equivallent of adding a *watch* for the varialbe in the debugger's watch window. It doesn't matter where you picked the *name* from.

Answer (score 1):

Porgram execution works on `stack` where program pushes `values` and `instructions` on it.

So *watch window* queries that "hashtable" for *name vs value* and shows you the result.

In this concrete case, you have 2 variables with the same name, one of them already available on the stack, so *watch window* simply shows its result.